# SQL Error on creation only in release jar file

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

An error occurs when I start my server in release mode only (using a jar file built with ANT)

I have attached an image with realease-run and IDE-run (using IntelliJ). I have no idea what to do, I tried everything, asking here is my last chance.

The part of code where the error occours is:

```
//[sqlmanager side] SQLManager.java:
public SQLManager(ServerLogger slogg)
{
    logger = slogg;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
                "postgres", "123");

        logger.Write("SQL Manager - connection enstablished 2/2");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        logger.Write("Errore Connessione SQL (SQL context)");
    }
}
```

---

```
//[server side] Server.java
   private void init_SQL_Database() {

        try {
            logger_pane.Write("SQL Manager - initing connection 1/2");

            sqlmanager = new SQLManager(logger_pane);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(serSchoolLib.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            logger_pane.Write("* Errore Connessione SQL (server context)");
        }

    }
```

This is the exception:

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    18:17] java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [18:17] java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] Server.SQLManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] Server.serSchoolLib.init_SQL_Database(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] Server.serSchoolLib.start(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] Server.ServerLogger.OKButtonActionPerformed(ServerLogger.java:278)
    [18:17] Server.ServerLogger.access$000(ServerLogger.java:22)
    [18:17] Server.ServerLogger$1.actionPerformed(ServerLogger.java:93)
    [18:17] javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [18:17] java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [18:17] java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    [18:17] java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[on the left -> Release Running (with error) | on the right -> running from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAanf.png)

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: Horrendous error handling. Do no ignore exceptions!!! Simply logging them and continuing as-if nothing went wrong is the same as ignoring them.

Comment: @Jens added Exception Trace in post

Comment: How do you start your application (please show the full commandline)

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing while running the program from an ANT built **.jar** file is that you are not including the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to build the ***.jar** file.
You should be able to refer to the static and dynamic references of the driver class when you are running your program, in your case the dynamic reference to your driver class is not happening - as it is not part of the jar file you are running (or you are not referring to this PostgreSQL JDBC driver while you're running your program).

You need to run the program adding the necessary reference to the driver jar and this issue that you've report should be resolved.